# Can only get react-native events to work with deprecated 'sendAppEventWithName' function

Tags: events, react-native

I'm trying to send an event to my app when a screenshot is taken. I got this working using the deprecated eventDispatcher sendAppEventWithName. I'm trying to get it working with RCTEventEmitter sendWithName but it doesn't work and I'm not sure why.  This is my function in native, which I have confirmed is getting called when a screenshot is taken:

```
- (void)screenshotEventReceived:(NSNotification *)notification {
  [self sendEventWithName:@"ScreenshotTaken" body:@"hello"];
}
```

JS that listens:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.eventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(NativeModules.ScreenshotManager);
    this.eventEmitter.addListener('ScreenshotTaken', () => {
      console.log('WE GOT AN EVENT!!!');
    }, {});
}
```

If I replace the `sendEventWithName` call in my Objective-C with `[self.bridge.eventDispatcher sendAppEventWithName:@"ScreenshotTaken" body:@"hello"];` then this works fine. I don't want to do this because it's deprecated, but don't understand why the non-deprecated way isn't working. I get the yellow box and warning saying "Sending 'ScreenshotTaken' with no listeners registered" when I take a screenshot.